# Calculus u-substitution, how to know when to use square root term for u?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, change-of-variable

I am trying to solve $$\int {1\over x^2+3}dx$$
When I look at solutions created by several online solvers, they use u-substitution and choose: $$u={\sqrt{3}\over{3}}x$$
then proceed with $$\int {1\over x^2+3}dx = \int {\sqrt{3}\over 3(u^2+1)}du$$
I've seen this approach used on several other types of problems where $u$ involves using a square root to get the denominator into a form that contains $u^2+1$ (or more generally $u^2+a^2$), but I don't understand how $u$ is being chosen.
I presume this step is more elementary algebra than calculus, but I've clearly missed the material that shows when and how to develop $u$ terms like this.

Would you please explain the steps involved in order to realize $u$ needs to contain a square root term, how to chose the right $u$, and how to apply it to get $u^2+1$ in the denominator?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why don't you try $u=2x$, and then maybe $u=5x$, and you might spot a pattern to see how you can be sure to get what you need in the denominator. It might also be easier to see what is happening if you write your substitutions as $x= (1/2)u$, etc.. (I'm assuming you know how to rationalize the denominator in an expression like $\sqrt{1/2}$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we know an antiderivative of$$\frac1{x^2+1}\tag1$$($\arctan(x)$), the idea is to transform $\frac1{x^2+3}$ in such a way that we get something like $(1)$. The simplest way is to do $x=\sqrt3\,u$ and $\mathrm dx=\sqrt3\,\mathrm du$; then$$\int\frac1{x^2+3}\,\mathrm dx$$becomes$$\int\frac{\sqrt3}{3(u^2+1)}\,\mathrm du.$$And$$x=\sqrt3u\iff u=\frac{\sqrt3}3x.$$

Comment: Thank you, what I'm asking though is how does the $\sqrt{3}$ cause the denominator to go to $u^2+1$. I guess this is more of an algebra question.

Comment: If $u=\frac{\sqrt3}3x$, then $x=\frac3{\sqrt3}u=\sqrt3u$, and therefore$$\frac1{x^2+3}=\frac1{3u^2+3}=\frac13\cdot\frac1{u^2+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of the function $\arctan(x)$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\arctan(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{1}{1 + x^{2}}
\end{align*}

So we are looking for a change of variable which makes the integrand resembles such derivative.

In order to factor out the number $3$, we make the substitution $x = \sqrt{3}u$, whence we get the integral:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2} + 3} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1 + u^{2}} = \frac{\arctan(u)}{\sqrt{3}} + c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}\right) + c
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps !